# Speech Removed from Speaker Playback when Playing Specific File

Tags: audio, youtube

Really weird problem I cannot get my head around. So playing the below youtube video using the speaker on my Windows Phone (Lumia 1520) I can hear all background music but no speech. This occurs whether I'm watching in a Youtube app or in the browser. If I use headphones I can hear the vocals fine.

What really puzzles me is that if I watch the video on the originally hosted site (link also below) using the phone speaker I can hear the vocal just fine.

I've tried out a couple of online left and right audio channel tests which all worked perfectly on the speaker.

Is this an isolated problem with how Youtube plays back audio? Is there something I could do to resolve this? I haven't noticed it for any other videos as of yet.

https://youtu.be/rVwfvpKKGHQ

http://www.giantbomb.com/videos/quick-look-medieval-moves-deadmunds-quest/2300-5275/

**UPDATE**

Tried ripping the audio from the Youtube page (which plays fine on my pc) and transferred it to my phone. Still no speech! Now I'm just playing a regular mp3 and it's still not working. If this isn't a channel issue and isn't a Youtube issue what is left?

Comment: Yup.  Pretty weird.  The exact behavior you describe sounds rather unlikely to occur if you tried different hardware.  I'd be curious whether it also happens with different software (different browser running on same  phone).  Just a curiosity-- I'm not expecting that such info will lead me to a detailed full answer for ya'.

Comment: Your update isn't surprising.  It seems the vocals are on a separate audio track.  So your ripping just grabbed the audio data from the one track.  The only part that remains weird, that I see, is why your Lumia phone plays the vocal audio track but only when headphones are plugged in.  I know that a computer can potentially detect when headphones are plugged in, but the end result that you describe does currently seem unexpected.